# Python Imaging Library (PIL) source code

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm having trouble in finding PIL source code.

The main page of the library http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ does not have any link to git repositories.

Is Pillow (https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow) repository correct project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PIL was never ported to Python 3, so Pillow forked the project and took it over. Pillow has [since been back-ported](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.7.0) to Python 2, but if you are working with Python 3, you must use Pillow. They are essentially the same.

If you want the *source code* of PIL, just download it and look within the files yourself. If you want the *documentation* for PIL, [this](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm) is a good reference.

Comment: I'm trying to submit a bug to the library and do not understand what project should be responsible for the bug.

Comment: Then Pillow would be the repository to submit a bug report, if it still exists within that library. Nobody is maintaining PIL anymore.

Comment: Submitted to Pillow: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2019

Answer (score 0):

No. I think it is difference project.
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
When you want to install pillow, you must uninstall PIL